# Kafka CASE error fieldSchema for field cannot be null

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I cannot run CASE expression on KSQL.

I set up a stream called api_log. The api_log stream consists of these information.

```
ksql> describe extended api_log;
Name                 : API_LOG
Type                 : STREAM
Key field            : 
Key format           : STRING
Timestamp field      : CREATED_ON
Value format         : AVRO
Kafka topic          : api.api_log(partitions: 1, replication: 1)

 Field            | Type                      
----------------------------------------------
 ROWTIME          | BIGINT           (system) 
 ROWKEY           | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system) 
 ID               | BIGINT                    
 CREATED_ON       | BIGINT                    
 UPDATED_ON       | BIGINT                    
 API_CODE         | VARCHAR(STRING)           
 API_MESSAGE      | VARCHAR(STRING)                    
 API_KEY          | VARCHAR(STRING)           
----------------------------------------------

Local runtime statistics
------------------------


(Statistics of the local KSQL server interaction with the Kafka topic api.api_log)
```

I try to use CASE for my KSQL syntax.

```sql
select api_log.status, 
case 
    when api_log.status = 200 then 'success' 
    else 'error' end as status 
from api_log limit 3;
```

It shows this result.

```
fieldSchema for field status cannot be null.
```

However, when I try to execute

```
ksql> select status from api_log limit 10;
200
200
200
200
200
200
200
200
200
200
Limit Reached
Query terminated
```

They are not null values.

Why it is not working????

Comment: Does it work if you don't alias the table? i.e. `select status, 
case 
    when status = 200 then 'success' 
    else 'error' end as status 
from api_log limit 3;`

Comment: This will cause `Failed to prepare statement: Cannot create field because of field name duplication STATUS
Caused by: Cannot create field because of field name duplication STATUS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of KSQL are you using?

I've just tried to recreate this in my environment running KSQL 5.3.0, and got an expected error (and better error message!):

```
ksql> select api_log.status,
>case
>    when api_log.status = 200 then 'success'
>    else 'error' end as status
>from api_log limit 3;
Cannot create field because of field name duplication STATUS
Statement: select api_log.status,
case
    when api_log.status = 200 then 'success'
    else 'error' end as status
from api_log limit 3;
Caused by: Cannot create field because of field name duplication STATUS
```

To solve this you should provide a different alias for the second status field:

```
ksql> select api_log.status,
>case
>    when api_log.status = 200 then 'success'
>    else 'error' end as human_status
>from api_log limit 3;
407 | error
404 | error
302 | error
Limit Reached
Query terminated
```

Comment: I used docker's latest tag. I still get the same error. `select status, case when status = 200 then 'success' else 'error' end as human_status from api_log limit 3;
fieldSchema for field HUMAN_STATUS cannot be null.`